# Windows Python 64 & 32 bit versions and pip

Tags: python, windows, pip, pyinstaller

I have made a simple python script and built a 64-bit Windows executable from it via pyinstaller. However, most computers at my office run 32-bit Windows operating systems, thus my program does not work. From what I have read, it is possible to make an executable for 32-bit systems as long as I use the 32-bit version of python. So I went ahead and installed the 32-bit version of python 3.5, but I can't find the way to link pip to the 32-bit version of python so I can install all the necessary modules. Every time I call pip it displays all the modules that are installed on the 64-bit version, even though by default I am running the 32-bit version python.

Comment: How are you running pip? Are you getting the right version of it (i.e. the version installed with the 32-bit version of Python)?

Comment: You need to use pip.exe that's in the Scripts folder of the 32-bit version of Python. Or you can run pip as a module using `py -3.5-32 -m pip install ...`.

Comment: Oh! Running pip from the 32-bit folder has actually worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're running `py -3.5-32 -m pip`, specifically with the -32 suffix, then there's no doubt that you're installing packages into a 32-bit version of Python. Otherwise py.exe would fail with the message "Requested Python version (3.5-32) not installed".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with both 32 and 64-bit versions of Python installed. I found if I ran the pip install in the command prompt from the location of pip.exe it worked fine. In my case, the file path was the following:

C:\Program Files\Python\3.5\Scripts

Comment: still ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.