# Python: No module named 'gym'

Tags: python, openai-gym

I have a really simple error, that plainly says there is no module called 'gym'. Which really sucks, mostly because I've always wanted to use the OpenAI (Gym and Universe) modules. I've run `pip install gym` and `pip install universe` without typos in my installation or importing.

Code:

```
import gym
import universe

env = gym.make('flashgames.CoasterRacer-v0')
obervation_n = env.reset()

while True:
    action_n = [[('KeyEvent', 'ArrowUp', True]) for ob in observation_n]
    observation_n, reward_n, done_n, info = env.step(action_n)
    env.render()
```

So what's going on, and how can I fix this (I'm using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGYU5t8MO7s))? Thanks.

**EDIT**: Okay, this is *weird*. I uninstalled Python, reinstalled it, reinstalled gym and universe, and now it says Universe can't be found. When I install Universe it gives me this error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mdg2jd74\fastzbarlight\
```

Is this an issue with Universe?

Comment: Do you have an example of your code? Is it just `import gym`?

Comment: Do you have multiple python versions installed? Chances are it is installed for a different version than the one you're trying to import it with. It's a pretty common mistake when multiple versions are present.

Comment: @brandon Yes, I'll put it in

Comment: @tgikal I might. I'm checking right now, thanks :)

Comment: @tgikal Okay, it looks like I have to 'Edit with IDLE' options (probably one 64 bit and one 32). Not sure how that happened. Should I just uninstall one and keep the other?

Comment: There is a syntax error on line 8. The parentheses and brackets don't match up.

Comment: I'd check here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015410/windows-python-64-32-bit-versions-and-pip, for installing 32 vs 64

Comment: Thanks, @brandon, I'll fix the error

Comment: I am able to run your code once I install the packages. I am using virtualenv and I do have to use `sudo ./env/bin/python my_file.py` to give the script permission and point to the right python binary.

Comment: @tgikal I uninstalled 32 bit python and reinstalled gym and universe. I still get the error

Comment: are you installing through a command line, or python itself?

Comment: @tgikal Command line

Comment: To be honest, I'm thinking of uninstalling Python and pip, and reinstalling them

Comment: Sorry, `pip.main` is depreciated, so it will no longer work.

Comment: Yeah, I've had screwy python installations before and it sucks trying to keep them straight, so I'm only have 1 version of python 3 at a time now. Python's guide may help if you haven't looked it over yet: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

Comment: @tgikal Now Gym seems to be fixed, but now Universe is all whacked up. Same error

Comment: I probably should have brought this up before, are you on windows? It's not very windows install-able: https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/982

Comment: @tgikal Yes, I do have windows. Does this mean I can't use openai?

Answer (score 1):

I too was facing the same error. In my case I had created another environment (gym_env) in Anaconda and launched Jupyter Notebook from the gym_env environment. That's why `import gym` wasn't working, as gym wasn't installed in this environment.
When I ran 'pip install gym' from gym_env then it started working.